# Mapping 3D models to kinect video output

Tags: kinect

I'm doing a project on Kinect device and I want to know how to map 3D body parts(Like in virtual dressing rooms) to kinect output video stream. This is the very important part in our final year project. Please I need help. I'm looking forward to hear from you.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you had the chance to look over the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit examples?  There is an example of how to map an avatar to the Kinect input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, you can use different kind of second-part software to create animated avatar. Cause you need to create here 3D avatar and animate it.
There is no one correct answer. You need to check how to combine this with your software.

One software needs a file with data in specific format, other just record your moves and create animated model on which you can put skins.

Comment: You are right it depends, I searched in the net but couldn't find any way to map a 3D model to a real video stream.Anyway I'll search for them more.